# how to create an empty case with line and board (NO MODULE( prettytable or)

Tags: python

I need an empty table with cells to fill 5x5
The user will fill and for that I need a variable, with cells(i think it's  " cells = ' ' like this)
user enters a number, for example x = 0 ; x = 1 ; value 5
for example **user_input = input('1. Enter X: \n2. Enter Y: \n3. Enter Value: ') next code -> if user_input == 1. (etc)**

```
board = list(range(0, 5))


def draw_board():
    print("*---*---*---*---*---*")
    for i in range(0, 5):
        print('|', board[0 + i * 0], '|', board[0 + i * 0], '|', board[0 + i * 0],
              '|', board[0 + i * 0], '|', board[0 + i * 0], '|')
    print("*---*---*---*---*---*")

    

draw_board()
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure of what exactly you want to accomplish with your code, but if I understand correctly you would like to create a graphical representation of a table in whose cells the user can add numeric values.

I've written some code that produces the desired output. Mind you, this code heavily relies on the graphic aspect; there are external libraries that offer much cleaner and more functional methods, but since you have specified that you don't want to import modules:

```
board = []
row = ["|","   |","   |","   |","   |","   |"]

for i in range(5):
    board.append(row)

# Ad this point you have created a graphical representation of a 5x5 table.

# The following function prompts the user to add in the value and the x,y position in the table at which it should be added.
def add_value():
    x = int(input("Add the row number: "))
    y = int(input("Add the column number: "))
    value = input("Insert the value: ")

    board[x-1][y] = f" {value} |"

# This function prints out the table.
def show_board():
    for row in board:
        print("*---*---*---*---*---*")
        print("".join(row))
    print("*---*---*---*---*---*")
```